# Image with dynamic src loads in Android browser, but not in Webview

Tags: java, android, webview

I am dynamically serving an image from my server, and attempting to display it in an img tag on an Android phone. This works perfectly in the normal Android browser, but when I try it in my app's Webview I just get a question mark.

Running Android 2.1.1 on a Nexus One

Comment: do you have any code of how you are setting the img resource in your application?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are asking. The image is just displayed in an html img tag on a web page.

Comment: show the code that works with static images and the code that doesn't work with the dynamic images. still, i don't know if I get what you mean by static vs dynamic image references...

Comment: Static: <img src="http://mywebsite.com/image1.jpg" />

Comment: Dynamic: <img src="http://mywebsite.com/retrieve?fileID=55" />

Answer (score 0):

Your application need access permission to the web.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: I have permission. I can load everything else from my server, including static images, the only things that aren't loading are the dynamically served images.

Comment: I believe the webview does not recognize the mimetype automatically of your dynamic image - because it does not have a extension.

Comment: Try to load it by public void loadData (String data, String mimeType, String encoding) or wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, mimeType, encoding, "") and change the DOM. It is a workaround.

Comment: Ugh... is there any other way? I would really like to maintain portability as much as possible. How does the built-in browser do it?

Comment: I don't know. Try something like <img src="http://mywebsite.com/retrieve?fileID=55&file.jpg" /> Maybe somebody else has a better answer for your question.